# how to get testng fail messages from command line

Tags: java, testng

I'm new to testng.  I want to see the Expected and Actual message when I run it from command line.
When I run it from my IDE, it works:

> java.lang.AssertionError:  Expected :3 Actual   :2

when I run it from the command line using:

```
java org.testng.TestNG -testclass SimpleTest
```

I get:

> Command line suite
>   Total tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Skips: 0

(no message) when I wrap my test in a try... catch block so it looks like:

```
try{
   int x = 3;
   Assert.assertEquals(2,x);
} catch (AssertionError ae){
   System.out.println(ae.getMessage());
}
```

then I get my message.

```
expected:<3> but was:<2>
```

This seems like not a clean way to code a test.  How would you do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TestNG doesn't provide this OOB. By default it generates a report in html.

If you want to write a report on the console, you need write a customs [`TestListenerAdapter`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/TestListenerAdapter.html).

There's a small example of how to do something similar in the TestNG [logging](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging) documentation. You can use the same example, and override `onTestFailure()`, read the result of the test, and get the exception message from `ITestResult.getThrowable()`.

Comment: thanks!  This is a great exercise to get into the testng API.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `-verbose 2` or a higher number.

Comment: Thank you!  I did see my message ( with a lot else ) so this is a way.  By the way, I have your book right next to me.