# testng xslt reports doesn't include failed test cases

Tags: eclipse, xslt, ant, selenium-webdriver

I have automated using TestNg framework in eclipse and I am not able to get the failed test cases reports in the final index.html file. Whenever I run the ant script through the command prompt I get all the test cases as fail/pass. but the reports don't seem to show failed cases. Below is the XML file I've used in my project. Apologize me if this is a little shabby. I have also double checked if the clean procedure gets called, but no luck. Any pointers/ideas/suggestions?

```
<project name="UAT_Automation" basedir="C:\Users\gthelu\workspace\TestCasesSuite">
<property name="home.dir" value="${basedir}"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="${home.dir}/build"/>
   <!--property name="jars" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\selenium jar's" -->
<property name="src.dir" value="${home.dir}/src"/>
<property name="ng.result" value="test-output"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="./Lib"/>
<property name="browser" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"/>
<property name="index.dir" value = "${basedir}/testng_output/index.html"/> 
<!-- setClassPath -->
<target name="setClassPath">
    <path id="classpath_jars">
        <pathelement path="${basedir}/" />
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
    </path>
    <pathconvert pathsep=":" property="test.classpath" refid="classpath_jars" />
 </target>
  <!-- loadTestNG -->
  <target name="loadTestNG" depends="setClassPath">
   <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${test.classpath}"/>
  </target>
   <!-- build -->
  <target name="build">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <tstamp>
        <format property="timestamp" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy_(HH-mm-ss)"/>
    </tstamp>
    <property name="build.log.dir" location="${basedir}/buildlogs"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.log.dir}"/>
      <property name="build.log.filename" value="build_${timestamp}.log"/>
     <record name="${build.log.dir}/${build.log.filename}" loglevel="verbose" append="false"/>
    <echo message="build logged to ${build.log.filename}"/>
</target>
    <!-- Clean -->
<target name="clean">
    <echo message="deleting existing build directory"/>
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>
    <!-- Compile -->
<target name="compile" depends="clean,build,setClassPath,loadTestNG">
    <echo message="classpath:${test.classpath}"/>
    <echo message="compiling.........."/>
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" srcdir="${src.dir}" classpath="${test.classpath}"/>
</target>
    <!-- executeApp -->
<target name="executeApp" depends="compile">
    <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${build.dir}">
        <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml"/>
    </testng>
</target>
    <!-- Report --> 
<target name="report" depends="executeApp">
    <delete dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt"/>
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt"/>
    <xslt in="${basedir}/test-output/testng-results.xml"
    style="${basedir}/src/xslt/testng-results.xsl" out="${basedir}/testng-xslt/index.html" processor="SaxonLiaison">
        <param expression="${basedir}/testng-xslt/" name="testNgXslt.outputDir"/>
        <param expression="true" name="testNGXslt.sortTestCaseLinks"/>
        <param expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,BY_CLASS" name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter"/>
        <param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals"/>
        <classpath refid="classpath_jars"/>
    </xslt>
</target>
     <!-- makexsltreports-->
<target name="makexsltreports" depends="executeApp">
    <exec executable="${browser}" spawn="yes">
   <arg line="${index.dir}" />
  </exec>
 </target>
    </project>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get testng fail messages from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756579/how-to-get-testng-fail-messages-from-command-line)